# Do I ask the editor of the rejecting journal where to submit next?

Tags: journals, editors, rejection

I got a rejection after one review cycle, with a comment that reviewer comments are useful and will help you in submission to another journal. Can I ask the editor's opinion on which journal to target?

Comment: You can ask, but be prepared not to get an answer.  In the situations I'm familiar with, the editor won't have studied your paper in enough detail to give you a useful answer, so the best (s)he can do would be to pass the question on to the reviewer.  But, considering the reviewer has already done some unremunerated work for the editor in reviewing the paper, the editor might not feel like bothering the reviewer again.

Comment: If you are a student and have an advisor, ask her or him.

Comment: Note that there's a difference between rejecting a paper because it's out of scope or doesn't meet quality level of *this* journal, and rejecting a paper because it doesn't seem publishable in general. In the latter case, the editor's statement that "reviewer comments... will help you in submission to another journal" *may* be just a way to cushion the blow of rejection, not an indication that the editor is actually recommending that you submit the paper (in anything like its current state) to another journal.

Comment: Possible , I guess asking him to recommend a journal is one way to find out

Comment: The editor can't tell you "go away, you have wasted enough of our time already". But that might be what he/she *means* by "rewrite your paper, then send it some place else."

Comment: @ff524, I'd hope editors/reviewers tell me the truth, if only to stop wasting my time.

Comment: *He who asks a question is a fool for five minutes; he who does not ask
a question remains a fool forever* – Chinese proverb

Comment: Being a native Chinese speaker, I can tell you this is not a Chinese proverb. You can refer to the question [Is this a Chinese Proverb?](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1862/808) on Chinese Language SE.

Comment: @scaaahu interesting, thanks! Being a person who likes to ask a lot of questions, I can tell you that it's a good proverb, whether it's Chinese or not. :-)

Comment: Great, so asking questions is, in general, important. That doesn't mean that asking a specific question to a specific journal editor who just rejected your paper is important, appropriate or useful. What *specific* advice do you have *for the actual situation the asker is in*?

Comment: The advice I have is in my answer. It is a good general principle which the OP's question reminded me of, and I thought he/she may find it helpful. Furthermore, this advice is applicable to a good number of questions on Academic SE, which often start with "is it okay to ask ...". I find it a sad commentary on the state of our society/academia when people are so afraid of offending someone by asking a simple question.

Comment: There can be varying degrees of rejection. When editors tell you to submit a paper to another journal, it means they really don't want to see it at their journal again. It doesn't mean they have a specific idea of where you should submit next.

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes a referee or editor will offer an unsolicited suggestion.  When that doesn't happen, asking for suggestions would be unconventional.  As an editor, if an established professional asked me for suggestions, I'd be a little annoyed (they should be able to figure that out themselves), and I'd give a terse reply like "Sorry, I'm not sure what the best place for your paper would be."  If a beginning researcher asked me, or anyone dealing with a truly unusual situation, I would try to be more helpful.  The response you get may depend on the editor, but the worst case scenario is probably annoying the editor a little and getting no reply.  (I don't think there's any risk of dreadfully offending anyone, assuming you don't press the editor further if he/she doesn't reply or seems impatient.)  I would ask the editor only if you don't have any mentors you could ask, but in that case it could be worth a try.

Answer (score 7):

They are telling you "this isn't good enough for our journal". They will be *very* reluctant (for professional courtesy if nothing else) to give a list of "lesser" (or "better, for that matter) journals in their area. Perhaps in a informal conversation in an aisle somewhere, never in writing.

They might suggest some if the problem is that the paper is out of scope, but that is not your case as I understand it.